how to fix vertex ai PERMISSION_DENIED
I am referring node js code from https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/start/quickstarts/quickstart-multimodal#gemini-beginner-samples-nodejs
On gcloud I am getting following error
{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Permission 'aiplatform.endpoints.predict' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/xxx/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/gemini-1.0-pro-vision' (or it may not exist).","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"
In vertex AI studio I have access to gemini-1.0-pro-vision. I understand for Node js I have to setup SA and provide access. My SA account has role of vertex ai administrator.
But I still get the error.
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file='keyfile.json'
Activated service account credentials for: [g-sa-ac@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com] <---- this s SA account with vertex user AI and admin access. 

Then, code is as below which is throwing this error
const streamingResult = await generativeVisionModel.**generateContentStream**(request);
    const contentResponse = await streamingResult.response;
    console.log(contentResponse.candidates[0].content.parts[0].text);

Any help highly appreciated. Thank you.

where do you run the node JS application? It is likely that you still need to setup Application Default Credentials for the service account. Check this doc https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc

Hi @user269867, In your service account you can add
aiplatform.endpoints.predict permission and try again. Refer to this doc.

Which IAM roles are assigned to g-sa-ac@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com in the project's IAM policy?

@JohnHanley was able to solve thanks

As mentioned by @Gang Chen, It is likely that you still need to setup Application Default Credentials for the service account. Check this documentation.
Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.
Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.
